# How to map two fields into a single property in React Final Form

Tags: react-final-form

In my app, I have two text fields, one for date and one for time. These fields need to map to a single property `startTime` in my form (of type Date). Is it possible to do this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try this - https://github.com/final-form/final-form-calculate? Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/oq52p6v96y

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! Put it as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:  [github.com/final-form/final-form-calculate](http://github.com/final-form/final-form-calculate)

Example: http://codesandbox.io/s/oq52p6v96y